# GeoFire + Swift+ Firebase : Save current location

Tags: swift, firebase, location, geofire

This is working:

```
geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: 37.7853889, longitude: -122.4056973), 
   forKey: "firebase-hq") { (error) in
  if (error != nil) {
    println("An error occured: \(error)")
  } else {
    println("Saved location successfully!")
  }
}
```

But how do I send my current location coordinate to my Firebase? Like this? but currentLocation doesn't work.

```
geoFire!.setLocation(currentLocation, forKey: "firebase-hq") { (error) in
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    print("An error occured: \(error)")
                                } else {
                                    print("Saved location successfully!")
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is completely necessary I would recommend not using GeoFire and instead use apple's inbuilt API. First, open your info.plist file as source code and add the following to the file

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Will you allow this app to always know your location? 
</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Do you allow this app to know your current location?</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Will you allow this app to always know your current location? 
</string>
```

Then add this code to your new viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class SearchViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager:CLLocationManager!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    determineMyCurrentLocation()
}


func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    // Call stopUpdatingLocation() to stop listening for location updates,
    // other wise this function will be called every time when user location changes.

    // manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")



}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}
}
```

This will print the your latitude and longitude as the default current location in your simulator as somewhere in San Francisco. To change this, go into you simulator and go into the debug menu and click location, current location and enter your preferred new values.

Comment: You need geofire so that you can later get users located within a certain radius. Otherwise, you can't.